# Prove an annulus is homeomorphic to a cylinder

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be the annulus

$A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \colon 1 \leq x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 4 \}$.

Prove that $A$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1} \times I$, where $I = [0,1]$ is the unit interval.

Define $f \colon S^{1} \times I \rightarrow A$, and $g \colon A \rightarrow S^{1} \times I$ by the following maps.

$$f(x,y,t) = ((t+1)x,(t+1)y)$$ and

$$g(u,v) =\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}},\frac{v}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}},\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}-1\right).$$

$f$ and $g$ are clearly well-defined.  Moreover, they and are continuous as their components are continuous.  Lastly, we must show that $f \circ g = I_{A}$ and $g \circ f = I_{S^{1} \times I}$, where $I$ is the identity function.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(g(u,v)) &=
f\bigg(\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}},\frac{v}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}},\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}-1\bigg) \\ 
&= \bigg( (\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}-1 + 1)\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}},(\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}-1 + 1)\frac{v}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}  \bigg) \\
&= (u,v).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
g(f(x,y,t)) 
&= g((t+1)x,(t+1)y) \\
&= \bigg(\frac{(t+1)x}{\sqrt{((t+1)x)^{2} + ((t+1)y)^{2}}},\frac{(t+1)y}{\sqrt{((t+1)x)^{2} + ((t+1)y)^{2}}}, \\
&\qquad  \sqrt{((t+1)x)^{2} + ((t+1)y)^{2}} -1\bigg) \\
&= \bigg( \frac{(t+1)x}{\sqrt{(t+1)^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})}}, \frac{(t+1)y}{\sqrt{(t+1)^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})}}, \sqrt{(t+1)^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})} -1\bigg) \\
&= \bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}, (t+1)\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}-1\bigg) \\
&= (x,y,t).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

I might look stupid after this, but I can't see why the last component on the second to last line is not working out.  Unless, my maps weren't defined correct?  Can someone see the problem?

Using the comments below, since $(x,y) \in S^{1}$, its norm $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} =1$.  Thus, the last line in the chain of equalities in the above equation holds.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my formatting!!

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$

Comment: @StefanHamcke what??  I am not following.  Plus, I need the $(t+1)$ in the last component to not be there for my proof to be done.

Comment: Since $(x,y)\in S^1$, its norm is $1$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke but I am not taking its norm.  I also do not see how that would fix my proof.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: You take the square root of the sum of the squares of the coordinates, and that is the norm of $(x,y)$. And this norm is equal to $1$ as the vector is from the unit sphere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35218/discussion-between-tim-and-stefan-hamcke).

Comment: I think you would find using polar coordinates would be a lot simpler working:  define f(r,θ) = (3(r-1), θ) and g(y,θ)=(1+3y, θ), it should be easy to see that points on the circle radius r, map to points on the cylinder around the circle at height 3(r-1) and similarly points on the cylinder at height y map to points on the circle 1+3y.  It is easy to see that the functions are mutual  inverses.

Comment: It would be nice to leave your question as written, and for you to answer it yourself, in the answers section.